# python open() escape backslash

Tags: python, io

I have a path to a file containing `$` signs, which I escaped with `\` so `open()` can handle the path. But now open turns the `\$` to a `\\$` automatically. 
For example:

```
open("/home/test/\$somedir\$/file.txt", "r")
result in an error message

IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/test/\\$somedir\\$/file.txt'
```

Can I supress this. Why `open()` do that? I can't find anything in the docu of open, which describes this.

Comment: $ don't need escaping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`open()` *doesn't* do that. It's Python, which escapes any special characters when representing a string:

```
>>> path = '\$'
>>> path
'\\$'
>>> print path
\$
```

In a regular Python string literal, a `\` has special meaning, so it is escaped when echoing back the value, which can be pasted right back into a Python script or interpreter session to recreate the same value.

On Linux or Mac, you generally do *not* need to escape a `$` value in a filename; a `$` has no special meaning in a regular python string, nor in most Linux or Mac filenames:

```
>>> os.listdir('/tmp/$somedir$')
['test']
>>> open('/tmp/$somedir$/test')
<open file '/tmp/$somedir$/test', mode 'r' at 0x105579390>
```

Comment: Maybe I missing something: I tried the following

open("/test/$somedir$/file.txt", "r") -> doesn't work

open(r"/test/$somedir$/file.txt", "r") -> doesn't work

open("/test/\$somedir\$/file.txt", "r") -> doesn't work

open(r"/test/\$somedir\$/file.txt", "r") -> doesn't work

Comment: `$` is *not* an escape code in Python strings, so using a raw string literal won't change anything.  What does `os.listdir('/test')` tell you the directory is named? If it *is* `$somedir$`, what does `os.lisdir('/test/$somedir$')` tell you is in that directory?

Comment: os.listdir('/test') shows me the $somedir$ but os.listdir('/test/$somedir$') results again in a OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:...

Comment: What platform is this? What filesystem (if on Linux)?

Comment: SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 11 (x86_64), ext3

Comment: @d.volery: I cannot reproduce your issue, not on ext4 in any case. Can you share the output of `os.listdir('/test')` at all?

Comment: Afther reboot it works with open("/test/$somedir$"). Don't know why.

Answer (score 1):

Try using a literal representation of the string adding `r` before the string variable to avoid dealing with more complex scape situations, for example:

```
print('C:\test')
#C:      est

print(r'C:\test')
#C:\test
```

where `\t` is interpreted as a `tab`.